# Validation tool or pattern for GWT

Tags: regex, validation, gwt

I am looking for a tool or a pattern to implement validation for GWT. Is there something that has embedded validation functionalities?

EDIT: I mean validations in forms

I installed STS with the GWT plugins, including GWT Designer, and it seems that I have to code my validation events and visual behaviours on top of an onblur empty event.

Is there an already existing tool or library that will simplify the development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below library.

http://gwt-vl.maydu.eu/ValidationShowcase.html

Answer (score 1):

If you need JSR-303 validation, have a look at [gwt-validation](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-validation/).